# Splunk search query

Tags: regex, splunk-query

```
index=au_axs_app_log
source =log
```

I wanted to write a SPLUNK where data in Response Code is greater 05. currently it displayed where data in this field is set as 00. Can you please share how can i write query where it would fetch desired results

```
EXT-ID[25]      FLD[Point of Service Condi..]  FRMT[FIXED]       LL[0]  LEN[2]    TYPE[String]             CHS[Binary Coded De..]  DATA[51]
EXT-ID[32]      FLD[Acquiring Institution ..]  FRMT[LVAR-Bin]    LL[1]  LEN[6]    TYPE[String]             CHS[Binary Coded De..]  DATA[320000]
EXT-ID[37]      FLD[Retrieval Reference Nu..]  FRMT[FIXED-Group] LL[0]  LEN[12]   TYPE[String]             CHS[EBCDIC]             DATA[203906284278]
+EXT-ID[37.1]   FLD[Julian Date and time]      FRMT[FIXED]       LL[0]  LEN[6]    TYPE[String]             CHS[ASCII]              DATA[203906]
+EXT-ID[37.2]   FLD[RRN Stan]                  FRMT[FIXED]       LL[0]  LEN[6]    TYPE[String]             CHS[ASCII]              DATA[284278]
EXT-ID[38]      FLD[Authorization Identifi..]  FRMT[FIXED]       LL[0]  LEN[6]    TYPE[String]             CHS[EBCDIC]             DATA[552572]
****EXT-ID[39]      FLD[Response Code]             FRMT[FIXED]       LL[0]  LEN[2]    TYPE[String]             CHS[EBCDIC]             DATA[00]****
EXT-ID[42]      FLD[Card Acceptor Identifi..]  FRMT[FIXED]       LL[0]  LEN[15]   TYPE[String]             CHS[EBCDIC]             DATA[320000000000001]
EXT-ID[49]      FLD[Currency Code, Transac..]  FRMT[FIXED]       LL[0]  LEN[3]    TYPE[String]             CHS[Binary Coded De..]  DATA[036]
EXT-ID[62]      FLD[Custom Payment Service..]  FRMT[LVAR-Bin-Group] LL[1]  LEN[18]   TYPE[String]             CHS[ASCII]              DATA[i)xg?P?@]
++EXT-ID[62.2]   FLD[62-2 Transaction Ident..]  FRMT[FIXED]       LL[0]  LEN[15]   TYPE[String]             CHS[Binary Coded De..]  DATA[869297810679250]
++EXT-ID[62.23]   FLD[62-23 Product ID]          FRMT[FIXED]       LL[0]  LEN[2]    TYPE[String]             CHS[Extended EBCDIC..]  DATA[A ]
```

Comment: What about `| rex "FLD\[Response Code\].*DATA\[(?<response_code>\d+)\]" | where response_code > 5`

Comment: Yes thanks. It works I have added as follows
| rex "EXT-ID\[39\].*\DATA\[(?<EXT_39_DATA>.*?)\]"

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a *full* regex for extracting all of the bracketed fields, this is the [most efficient](https://regex101.com/r/R7vfay/1) one-shot I could make:

```
| rex field=_raw "(?<extid>[\d\.]+).+D\[(?<fieldtype>[^\]]+).+T\[(?<format>[^\]]+).+L\[(?<ll>[^\]]+).+N\[(?<len>[^\]]+).+E\[(?<type>[^\]]+).+S\[(?<charset>[^\[]+).+A\[(?<data>[^\]]+)"
```

Most often I do sequential [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex) calls, just in case some fields aren't present in all events, but your sample data shows each of these items present

Once you've extracted *every* field in the data, you can [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) or [`search`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/search) it any way you may like (I see some of your "`FLD`" (which I've named "`fieldtype`") values can have spaces or punctuation, so I'm using the wildcard `search` feature to match anything that looks like "Response Code"):

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp 
| rex field=_raw "(?<extid>[\d\.]+).+D\[(?<fieldtype>[^\]]+).+T\[(?<format>[^\]]+).+L\[(?<ll>[^\]]+).+N\[(?<len>[^\]]+).+E\[(?<type>[^\]]+).+S\[(?<charset>[^\[]+).+A\[(?<data>[^\]]+)"
| search fieldtype="Response*" 
| stats count by extid data fieldtype
| fields - count
| where tonumber(data)>5
```

[`tonumber`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/ConversionFunctions#tonumber.28NUMSTR.2CBASE.29) is quite flexible; I'm using it here in its simplest form